# Azure function 2 Dependency injection throwing error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a simple trigger that is bound to a Service bus topic. I am trying to inject another service into the trigger but i am receiving an error:

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to
>   resolve service for type 'AzureSearchSBTrigger.SimpleClass' while
>   attempting to activate 'AzureSearchSBTrigger.AzureServiceTrigger'.

If it remove the constructor the trigger works correctly and i can receive messages, etc.

This is an Azure function 2 (.net core) with Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12332.0

This is how it is setup (and not working)

The main function :

```
public AzureServiceTrigger(SimpleClass apiClient)
{
}

[FunctionName("AzureServiceTrigger")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("","",Connection = "SBConnectionString")]Message myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
}
```

StartUp

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(StartUp))]
namespace AzureSearchSBTrigger
{
    internal class StartUp : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<SimpleClass>();
        }
    }
}
```

Simple Class

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    public void Somethingsimple()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed by updating the nuget package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions from 1.0.24 -> 1.0.26

Comment: I still got the issue despite I am now on 1.0.28

Comment: Works for me on 1.0.29

Answer (score 0):

Use anything below Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.1. I had 3.0.2 and I got this error, I had to downgrade but than again am using ASP.NetCore 2.2, so not sure if that has much to do with it